# What's the percentage of primes in ranges $[0,\frac{n}{2}]$ and $[\frac{n}{2},n]$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Ran a loop to determine the number of primes in the ranges

$[0,\frac{n}{2}]$ and $[\frac{n}{2},n]$

The results show the number of primes in $[\frac{n}{2},n]$ approaching 48%

```
n = 10000000   (0,5000000)=348513   (5000000,10000000)=316066 (47.56%)
n = 11000000   (0,5500000)=380800   (5500000,11000000)=345717 (47.59%)
n = 12000000   (0,6000000)=412849   (6000000,12000000)=375211 (47.61%)
n = 13000000   (0,6500000)=444757   (6500000,13000000)=404495 (47.63%)
n = 14000000   (0,7000000)=476648   (7000000,14000000)=433429 (47.63%)
n = 15000000   (0,7500000)=508261   (7500000,15000000)=462443 (47.64%)
...
...
...
n = 200000000   (0,100000000)=5761455   (100000000,200000000)=5317482 (47.99%)
```

However, as $n\to\infty$, do both ranges settle at a final number, say 50/50?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This follows from the prime number theorem: the number of primes less than $x$ is about

$$\pi(x)\sim \frac{x}{\ln(x)}$$

Then

$$\pi(n)\sim \frac{n}{\ln(n)}\sim 2 \frac{n}{2\ln(n)-2\ln(2)}=2\frac{\frac{n}{2}}{\ln\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}\sim 2\pi\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$$

Thus $\frac{\pi(n)}{2}\sim \pi\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$ as you conjectured.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

QC_QAOA has shown that the ratio $\pi(n/2)/\pi(n)$ converges to $1/2$.  To that I'd add that you have

$$ {\pi(n/2) \over \pi(n)} \sim {(n/2)/\log(n/2) \over n/\log n} =  {1 \over 2} {\log n - \log 2 \over \log n} = {1 \over 2} \left( 1 - {\log 2 \over \log n} \right). $$

and so convergence  to $1/2$ will be quite slow - for example to get up to 0.49 you'll have to have $n = 2^{50} \approx 10^{15}$ which will be impractical if you're counting the primes directly.